# Creation of Virtual Machine with VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone fails

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vcenter, vmware-converter

I'm trying to convert my physical system to vm. And i'm trying to use VMware vCenter Converter. I was trying to follow the instrustions on this article: **http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-missioncritical-pc-vm-dies/**

I run program then clicked on "**Convert machine**" button. I selected power-on machine as the source and "**This local machine**" option. Then i clicked **Next** button. But it gives me this error message: "**Permission to perform this operation was denied**"

When i searched it, i came across this on VMware's knowledge base: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2043326

It's saying this error issue occurs when the user account does not have sufficient permissions on pc. But the thing is, i only have 1 account on my pc and it has all the authorization on os.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional

How can i solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Is the one user account you are using the builtin local admin account? Are you on a domain?

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand what you meant by "builtin local admin account" and "are you on a domain"? But, It's the user account when i installed windows

Answer (score 1):

When starting VMware Converter, right click on the program icon and click 'Run as Administrator' and it should give you the correct permissions. I do not use windows often, but I am assuming even though you are an administrator, windows still runs programs as a standard user unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is part of a domain the converter will not work. I think it is a vmware bug . You need to take it out of the windows domain and join it to local workgroup as any standalone machine. Logon as administrator and it works.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Do you have any bug reports to support this or is this a personal position? Thanks